# Is there a way to use environment variables within lambda layers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables, aws-lambda-layers

I am using lambda layers to share code between my lambda functions. Within the lambda layers code I would like to use ENV variables. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda layer share the same execution unit of a lambda function, so you have to define the environment variables of your lambda layer in all your lambda functions because each lambda function has its own environment section.

In case, the lambda layer config values are common across all the lambda functions, then consider using the default value for those fields. However, let the lambda functions to override those values from their execution environment.

Alternatively, if you want to maintain your lambda layer config in a centralised location, then consider using other AWS resources like SSM Parameter Store/AppConfig, Secrets manager, or DynamoDb. But, in this approach, you have to grant your lambda functions to access the external AWS resource that is used to preserve the config values of your lambda layer.